# Unity: Animation won't play on trigger

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator

Im having trouble to let Unity play my animations.
I gave my character an Animator. In this Animator I have this Animations:
[image: Animator]

The trigger between these Animations are working fine and are running correctly on play. The idle animation it self is played, while i can't get it to play the walk or the jump Animation in the game (both work fine in the inspector).
When on play the triggers are triggered, it even shows the blue bar under the walking or the jumping box, but the animation itself just wont be played in the game.

Here is the code I use to call the triggers:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)|| Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)||Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            anim.SetBool("isWalk", true);
            
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isWalk", false);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            anim.SetBool("isJump",true);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isJump", false);
        }
        
    }
```

And the Transition Conditions (but these are working fine for me):

```
idle->jump: isJump =true,
jump->idle: isJump =fals,
idle->walk: isWalk =true,
walk->idle: isWalk =false,
```

screenshot of idle-> walk:

[image: idle->walk]

screenshot of walk->idle:

[image: walk->idle]

I hope someone can help me with this and please excuse my possibly bad english...

Comment: You should provide more information please, like your triggers and the transitions settings in your animator, the code you are using to call the trigger.

Comment: i thought that woudnt be needed, because the triggers and transitions are working fine. It is just about the animation that wont play in the game.

Comment: You are new to this community, here is a basic rule: usually, no one can answer your question if you don't provide **more relevant information**  like your scripts, or everything related to your problem. This is probably not a bug from Unity, so please edit your question with the relevant part of your script, and the triggers/transitions.

Comment: i edited what you asked for

Comment: Your code seems indeed fine, can you post a screenshot of the animator component in the editor? And can you post a screenshot of the transition idle->walk and walk->idle please?

Comment: im not sure what you mean with the animator component, but i hope this is the right one

Comment: I can't find the problem sorry, but now that more information is available maybe someone will answer you. If the topic is not moving, then try to investigate, add more info like the settings of the transitions, and eventually upload a minimal project so people can see what is wrong themselves.

Comment: thanks for trying though

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Solved it by unchecking 'Can Transition To Self' inside the transition pointing to the state that didn't play.